# Static function returns unexpectedly when called from constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, unity-game-engine, static-methods

I'm not sure why, but I'm experiencing strange behaviour in my struct when constructing it.

Here's the code of the struct I'm constructing. This code is part of a "Step" class, which I use to represent a "Step" of a character in my game (my game is grid-based). direction and length are the only 2 fields in the struct, and they're readonly, making the struct immutable (I hope)

```
public Step(Direction d, int l)
{
    direction = d;
    if(l < 0) l = 0;
    length = l;
}

public Step(float horizontal, float vertical, int l) : this(getDirectionFromInputAxes(horizontal, vertical), l){
}

public static Direction getDirectionFromInputAxes(float horizontal, float vertical)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    if(horizontal < -0.5f){
        x += -1;
    }else if(horizontal > 0.5f){
        x += 1;
    }
    if(vertical > 0.5f){
        y += -1;
    }else if(vertical < -0.5f){
        y += 1;
    }

    switch(x){
    case -1:
        switch(y){
        case -1:
            return Direction.Northwest;
        case 0:
            return Direction.West;
        case 1:
            return Direction.Southwest;
        }
        break;
    case 0:
        switch(y){
        case -1:
            return Direction.North;
        case 0:
            return Direction.None;
        case 1:
            return Direction.South;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        switch(y){
        case -1:
            return Direction.Northeast;
        case 0:
            return Direction.East;
        case 1:
            return Direction.Southeast;
        }
        break;
    }

    // Should never happen
    return Direction.None;
}
```

Basically, I made a second constructor that takes floats (for convenience), and then the idea is that a Direction is created from the floats using a static function, and the class is then initialized with the main constructor.

I've been having some issues in my code. While debugging, I've noticed that the direction field in Step was for some reason "unloaded" when trying to read its value in Monodevelop. After putting some breakpoints in the constructor and the getDirectionFromInputAxes() function, I noticed that the static function is entered from the second constructor, but as soon as I step, the function is exited and it seems to jump to the main constructor, as if the function has returned. In the main constructor, d is undefined, but l is defined. This results in a Step object with no defined direction, but a defined length, which causes other problems in the code

I'm not sure why this is happening. My theory is that it's wrong to call a static function from a constructor. But why would that be the case? Perhaps I'm using enums incorrectly?

(any constructive comments on my style would be appreciated)

EDIT: Fixed a mistake. Step is actually a struct, not a class. Although I've tried changing it to a class and the problem still occurs.

EDIT2: The code that throws the NullReferenceException is the second line of the following:

```
Step step = new Step(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 1);
if((step.direction == Step.Direction.None && step.length == 0) || 
   (!FieldData.player.isValidStep(step))
  ){
    // We can't take this step. Ignore.
    break;
}
```

This code is located in another class. I'm guessing that the NullReferenceException occurs because `step.direction` is undefined inside the if statement, at least from what I can see in the debugger. `step` however is clearly a valid reference.

Comment: Do you mean Unity3d game engine? It is a different tag.

Comment: Have you tried changing the method from `static` to a non-static? Have you tried to add `Debug.Log` at the first line of the method, does it print anything?

Comment: Also, is it a `MonoBehaviour` subclass? You shouldn't use constructors with them because of Unity3d limitations.

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html

Comment: Try syncing your Monodevelop project. If Monodevelop falls out of sync, then its debug step-through will NOT make any sense. To do that, go Assets-> Sync Monodevelop Project in Unity.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on what MonoDevelop shows in the debug mode. It's not rare that it acts weird. Your code looks innocent for me (though it can be written in more elegant way). How does code act in the game itself? P.S. And, yes, if it's MonoBehaviour's descendant, then it is not supposed to have any constructor.

Comment: Yes, I meant Unity3D. I see the tag was fixed
No, it's not a MonoBehaviour-derived class, although a MonoBehaviour-derived class does use this (but I don't see the problem here)
The method needs to be static otherwise I couldn't call it from the constructor initializor
I've synced my monodevelop project. The problem still occurs. I get a 
I also seem to have been mistaken when writing the question. The "Step" class is actually a struct. Since I only need 2 small immutable values I thought it would be better if I used a struct. I've tried changing it to a class but the problem still occurs

Comment: Have you tried to execute your static method strictly from the constructor (between `{}`), not from the initialisation list?

Comment: I just tried that. I get the exact same problem. When the static method is entered, as soon as I step in the debugger, it immediately jumps to the code that created the Step struct. The direction field in the "constructed" struct ends up being invalid, which is how I know the constructor was not executed correctly. I'm starting to suspect that this is a unity problem, not my code.

Comment: @SergeyKrusch the code acts strange in the game itself. The direction field, which I need to read in another class, cannot be read. I get a NullReferenceException. This is only for the direction field of the struct. The length seems to be readable however, and the created struct is not null

Comment: NullReferenceException means that the problem lies somewhere else. Not in the code that you have shown (because both enums and structs are not nullable)

Comment: Can you show the code that throws NullReferenceException?

Comment: @SergeyKrusch Added the code in the question (see EDIT2). Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Well, I would say that either `FieldData` or `player` is null.

Comment: @SergeyKrusch ... you're right. player was null. I can't believe this. Monodevelop is mostly to blame for me not realizing this because of the confusing messages saying how the direction field was unloaded. I'm not sure what to do with this question now, it doesn't really have an answer. Perhaps I should just delete it?

Comment: @9a3eedi: There is still a valid answer here involving why Unity projects exit code when there's an exception instead of crashing properly. I shall write one up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity halts code and returns from the current function when an exception occurs, instead of crashing fully. They do this so they can log the error and not just close Unity every time. This behaviour is not limited to constructors or static methods, and can be a common cause of confusion for inexperienced (and even experienced) Unity programmers.

When this happens you should look for causes of the given exception in your code. There will be hints in the console output. In your case it was a `NullReferenceException`, which is caused by trying to access a field, property or method of a null value. In your case (From the comments), it was caused by `player` being null.

MonoDevelop loads and unloads variable data as they go in and out of scope. Unfortunately, this feature does not play well with Unity at all, and often it will unload variables that are most definitely in scope. This is a problem with MonoDevelop itself, and from [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/417448/the-requested-item-has-been-unloaded.html?page=2&pageSize=5&sort=votes) on Unity Answers it seems like it's not an easy fix.

Comment: This explains a lot of the strange behaviour I was facing while debugging, so I'm marking this an answer. As for variable data being loaded and unloaded, I guess I'm going to have to make do with that. I kinda experienced similar debugging scenarios when debugging optimized C code